# does index improve performance when sorting results of a join

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, query-performance

I want to order the result of a join between 4 tables - **Will creating an index for the order by column (b.SITE_ID) improve query performance?**

```
SELECT b.SERVICE_ID, b.ATT_ID, b.SITE_ID, b.ATT_VALUE, c.KEY_NAME, d.NAME as account_name
FROM SITE_ATTRIBUTES a , SF_SITE_ATTRIBUTES b, ATTRIBUTE_DEF c,SF_SITE_MASTER d 
WHERE  a.SERVICE_ID=b.SERVICE_ID 
  and  b.SERVICE_ID=c.SERVICE_ID  
  and  b.SERVICE_ID=d.SERVICE_ID 
  and  b.SERVICE_ID=@service_id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
  and b.ATT_ID= c.ID  
  and b.ATT_ID= a.ATT_DEF 
  and a.SITE=b.SITE_id  
  and b.SITE_ID = d.ID 
  and a.value != b.att_value 
  and b.att_value is not null 
ORDER BY b.SITE_ID
```

Thinking it won't since the order takes place over the intermediary joins result set...

Comment: I think it does. But you should try and check the explain analyze.  Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Please read this DBA Stack Exchange question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/order-by-column-should-have-index-or-not ... the answer is maybe, probably yes

Comment: And you really should read this. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: For background, see links in this [dba answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44627/1064). Also, [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html). But is it *that* hard to just create the index, and measure the difference?

Comment: Please rewrite using `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`b.SERVICE_ID=@service_id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` Is inefficient since it requires changing collation on the fly.  Change it so `SERVICE_ID` is declared `COLLATE tf8_unicode_ci` *and* your connection is using that collation.  Then...

```
INDEX(SERVICE_ID, SITE_ID)
```

would probably be the best --

1. Filter on `SERVICE_ID`;
2. Avoid sort by having `SITE_ID`.

The rest of the filtering (`!=` and `NOT NULL`) is unavoidable via indexing.

Just plain `INDEX(SITE_ID)` is probably not as good for *this* query.